# Flexible org TODO dependencies?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'd like to have `org-mode` do what [OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus/) does; when the bottom task in a sequential list is completed, the next task in the list becomes visible in an Agenda. Any thoughts on how I might try to tackle this problem?

I'd essentially like to write a tree with the leaves and only the leaves visible in some Agenda.

I'd be willing to try something like

```
* PENDING buy milk
** PENDING go to store
*** PENDING get in car
**** TODO find car keys
**** TODO put on pants
```

Where "get in car" automatically goes from `PENDING` to `TODO` when "find car keys" and "put on pants" are marked `DONE` in some Agenda. Ideally, though, I'd just create a special list of items all at the same level and mark the bottom one `TODO`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [org-depend.el](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-depend.html). It does exactly what you want. Rather than repeating the documentation here you can see docs and examples at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-depend.html

Comment: Thanks, this works. You can even nest lists with a little practice. Notes for the novice: you have to remove the leading commas from the example file if you're pasting it out of the above link. Also, to get this to work I had to
1) add (add-to-list 'load-path "~/org/lisp") to the top of my .emacs file,
2) paste the raw org-depend.el file into ~/org/lisp/org-depend.el, and
3) add (require 'org-depend) to the bottom of my .emacs file,
probably because my Emacs is installed from the Ubuntu Emacs Daily Snapshot PPA.